# Filtering by timespan and making it distinct

Tags: solr

I am looking for a way to get a list of every unique user who was active within a certain timespan(from now and ten minutes ago).  Using facets I'm able to get every unique user, but I'm still unable to get them in the said timespan("q=date_update:[NOW-10MINUTE TO NOW] doesn't seem to work).

Comment: I'd have a look at how you are indexing time, especially regarding the timezone. Remember that Solr uses UTC.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

date_update:[NOW-2MINUTE/MINUTE TO NOW/MINUTE]

Also, make sure you commit changes. That could also be a problem because of short time span.